# React useContext - store.getState is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-context

I'm trying to set up a global state store in my React application with useContext.  I'm getting an error within the  component but cannot figure out what is causing it...

[image]

./app/store.ts

```
import {createContext} from 'react';

export interface StoreInterface {
  somedata: string[],
  somemoredata: string[],
}

export type GlobalContextType = {
  context: StoreInterface ,
  setContext: (c: StoreInterface ) => void
};

const GlobalContext = createContext<GlobalContextType>({
  context: {somedata: [], somemoredata:[]},
  setContext: ()=>{}
});

export default GlobalContext;
```

App.tsx

```
import GlobalContext, {StoreInterface} from './app/store';

function App() {
  const [context, setContext] = useState<StoreInterface>({somedata: [], somemoredata: []});

  return(
    <GlobalContext.Provider value = {{context, setContext}}>
      <MyApp/>
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you have the `getStore` function

Comment: I see... I was referencing this link (https://dev.to/madv/usecontext-with-typescript-23ln) which also didn't use a getStore method unless I'm missing it.  Is it necessary to use getStore with useContext and no redux?

Comment: You have to pass following `value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}` in `.Provider`. And in your provided code I can't see where you created reducer and respective state for Global State setup like redux. You can follow this [Blog](https://codeburst.io/global-state-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-87019cc4f2cf)

Comment: Please show entire stack trace of the error. Seems like there is some code in `MyApp` that you didn't show

Comment: @GodWin, I was under the impression that creating a reducer and using a flux pattern was not a necessary precondition.  I'd like to avoid a flux style pattern if I can.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I've updated to show a screenshot of the stack trace.  As far as the MyApp code, I actually replaced that with just an empty div to test whether that would have an effect and it does not change the result.

Comment: Can you show `package.json`?

Comment: Ok very insightful question.  I just took a look at my package.json and saw I have react-redux in there.  I had previously been using it in the project before trying to switch to just useContext.  And now that error is gone and everything is working... thanks @KonradLinkowski!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo.

Change:

```
<GlobalContext.Provider/>
```

To this:

```
</GlobalContext.Provider>
```

React thought you have to providers probably

Comment: Argh that is my bad, sorry - I have it correct in my code but made a mistake when I was creating the question.  I'll correct that in the question here...